# Acento agudo vs circunflexo

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática, ortografia, português-europeu

Estava a dar uma pesquisada sobre isso, pois eu sabia que no Brasil geralmente se escreve, por exemplo, gênero, enquanto em Portugal é género, e acabei achando no site Norma Culta o seguinte

> O Novo Acordo Ortográfico possibilita a existência da dupla grafia de
>   várias palavras, admitindo tanto o acento circunflexo como o acento
>   agudo. A forma com o acento circunflexo é a utilizada no português do
>   Brasil e a forma com o acento agudo é a usada no português de
>   Portugal.

Desta forma, é correto utilizar o acento agudo no Brasil e vice e versa?

Comment: Há problema nenhum em escrever com acento agudo no Brasil ou circunflexo noutros países. O máximo que pode acontecer é alguém tentar corrigi-lo e a mudança na pronúncia.

Answer (score 2):

Frequentemente normas institucionais ditam apenas que se use a norma padrão do português e, portanto, como ambas as formas são corretas, não estaria errado nesse caso usar a acentuação de qualquer das variações da língua portuguesa.

Como coloca o [Portal da Língua Portuguesa](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/?action=novoacordo-present), sobre o Acordo Ortográfico de 1990:

> sendo cada forma variante de uma palavra oficialmente aceite como representante válida da língua portuguesa como um todo

Dito isso, não raramente a variação que deve ser adotada é especificada pelas normas (da universidade, empresa, agência, etc.), caso em que as grafias correspondentes devem ser utilizadas. E, mesmo quando não explícito, a mistura das variações (e.g., pt-PT e pt-BR) em geral deve ser evitada, dado o estranhamento que tende a causar. Como coloca o site citado acima:

> Isto não implica, portanto, que todas as formas de cada palavra sejam igualmente aconselháveis em todos os espaços geográficos.

Essa mistura não é recomendada devido à possibilidade de ser causa de distração ou, especialmente no contexto do ensino da língua, de confusão. Se a mistura de variações for adotada, é via de regra recomendado manter ao menos a consistência interna do texto, ou seja, evitar alternar entre pt-PT e pt-BR para a grafia de uma mesma palavra.